# How to create a bordered UILabel?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create a bordered UILabel on iOS. So far I read quite a few things here on SO and other websites on how to do that. But even though I'm able to get the border working I can't get the padding (insets) to work. It could be something related to my XCode layout, or something else I really don't know...

Here's the current result without insets:

[image]

This is the code that generated that:

```
SelectedServiceLabel.Font = Tools.Style.GetFont(Tools.Style.FontStyle.Regular, 15);
SelectedServiceLabel.TextColor = Tools.Style.PrimaryColor;
SelectedServiceLabel.Layer.BorderColor = Tools.Style.PrimaryColor.CGColor;
SelectedServiceLabel.Layer.CornerRadius = 3;
SelectedServiceLabel.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
SelectedServiceLabel.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
```

Here's the result using insets:

[image]

Here's the code:

Same as above with this addition:

`(SelectedServiceLabel as UIPaddedLabel).Insets = new UIEdgeInsets(1, 2, 1, 2);`

UIPaddedLabel derives from PaddedLabel seen here:

```
public class PaddedLabel : UILabel
{
    public PaddedLabel(IntPtr handle) : base (handle){}

    public UIEdgeInsets Insets { get; set; }

    public override void DrawText(CGRect rect)
    {
        base.DrawText(Insets.InsetRect(rect));
    }
}
```

These implementations I got from answers here on SO.

So my question is... how can I create a bordered UILabel that will actually hold the text completely inside the borders? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you increase the width of label and check

Comment: I'm not setting that statically. I'm using stack layout. Is there a way to do that using the Storyboard with the stack layout?

Comment: Can you try decreasing the font size just to check.

Comment: @user2071152 if I do set a smaller text it works (smaller text == less chars)... so maybe it is related to the space available, I just have no idea how to tell the label to stretch up and down. I'm new to iOS design. I'm using Storyboard and StackViews. Thanks.

Comment: @user2071152 thanks I fixed it by adjusting the sizes. I figured out how to do it using the Storyboard

Comment: SelectedServiceLabel.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;